# "Converting" Numpy arrays to Matlab and vice versa

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I am looking for a way to pass NumPy arrays to Matlab.

I've managed to do this by storing the array into an image using `scipy.misc.imsave` and then loading it using `imread`, but this of course causes the matrix to contain values between 0 and 256 instead of the 'real' values.

Taking the product of this matrix divided by 256, and the maximum value in the original NumPy array gives me the correct matrix, but I feel that this is a bit tedious.

is there a simpler way?

Comment: I forget, does Matlab allow parsing text files? Because you could just format the numpy arrays as Matlab-style ones in strings, write them to a file, and then read the arrays into Matlab.

Comment: Did you consider mlabwrap http://mlabwrap.sourceforge.net/#description

Comment: are you sure you cannot do the calculation entirely in numpy/scipy? just wondering

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I would be able to convert the Matlab implementation of a PLSM algorithm to numpy, but to solve all the problems caused by off-by-ones and difference in functions is very time-consuming. Thanks for the tip @JAB, it's less tedious than converting it to an image first. However, I might come across 3D matrices later, so Joe's solution works out for me.

Comment: @dilipkumbham that python-to-matlab bridge looks promising! Will check it out.

Comment: MATLAB can read and write HDF5 format, and there are python libraries. ..

Comment: related question: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/359680-can-someone-provide-me-an-example-of-loading-data-from-python-to-matlab

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Sure, just use `scipy.io.savemat`

As an example:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.io

x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
y = np.cos(x)

scipy.io.savemat('test.mat', dict(x=x, y=y))
```

Similarly, there's `scipy.io.loadmat`.

You then load this in matlab with `load test`.

Alteratively, as @JAB suggested, you could just save things to an ascii tab delimited file (e.g. `numpy.savetxt`).  However, you'll be limited to 2 dimensions if you go this route.  On the other hand, ascii is the universial exchange format. Pretty much anything will handle a delimited text file.

Comment: so this allows to save a numpy array to a file and then have it be read by matlab with something like `load('test.mat')`?

Comment: will using the `data.npz` or `data.npy` won't work? If not why not?

Comment: thank u, exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 13):

**A simple solution, without passing data by file or external libs.**

Numpy has a method to transform ndarrays to list and matlab data types can be defined from lists. So, when can transform like:

```
np_a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
mat_a = matlab.double(np_a.tolist())
```

From matlab to python requires more attention. There is no built-in function to convert the type directly to lists. But we can access the raw data, which isn't shaped, but plain. So, we use `reshape` (to format correctly) and `transpose` (because of the different way MATLAB and numpy store data). **That's really important to stress: Test it in your project, mainly if you are using matrices with more than 2 dimensions.** It works for MATLAB 2015a and 2 dims.

```
np_a = np.array(mat_a._data.tolist())
np_a = np_a.reshape(mat_a.size).transpose()
```

Comment: Note that `mat_a = matlab.double(np_a.tolist())` can be horribly inefficient/slow. Go with Joe Kington's answer for anything other than np arrays. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45284125/2524427

Answer (score 6):

Here's a solution that avoids iterating in python, or using file IO - at the expense of relying on (ugly) matlab internals:

```
import matlab
# This is actually `matlab._internal`, but matlab/__init__.py
# mangles the path making it appear as `_internal`.
# Importing it under a different name would be a bad idea.
from _internal.mlarray_utils import _get_strides, _get_mlsize

def _wrapper__init__(self, arr):
    assert arr.dtype == type(self)._numpy_type
    self._python_type = type(arr.dtype.type().item())
    self._is_complex = np.issubdtype(arr.dtype, np.complexfloating)
    self._size = _get_mlsize(arr.shape)
    self._strides = _get_strides(self._size)[:-1]
    self._start = 0

    if self._is_complex:
        self._real = arr.real.ravel(order='F')
        self._imag = arr.imag.ravel(order='F')
    else:
        self._data = arr.ravel(order='F')

_wrappers = {}
def _define_wrapper(matlab_type, numpy_type):
    t = type(matlab_type.__name__, (matlab_type,), dict(
        __init__=_wrapper__init__,
        _numpy_type=numpy_type
    ))
    # this tricks matlab into accepting our new type
    t.__module__ = matlab_type.__module__
    _wrappers[numpy_type] = t

_define_wrapper(matlab.double, np.double)
_define_wrapper(matlab.single, np.single)
_define_wrapper(matlab.uint8, np.uint8)
_define_wrapper(matlab.int8, np.int8)
_define_wrapper(matlab.uint16, np.uint16)
_define_wrapper(matlab.int16, np.int16)
_define_wrapper(matlab.uint32, np.uint32)
_define_wrapper(matlab.int32, np.int32)
_define_wrapper(matlab.uint64, np.uint64)
_define_wrapper(matlab.int64, np.int64)
_define_wrapper(matlab.logical, np.bool_)

def as_matlab(arr):
    try:
        cls = _wrappers[arr.dtype.type]
    except KeyError:
        raise TypeError("Unsupported data type")
    return cls(arr)
```

The observations necessary to get here were:

- Matlab seems to only look at `type(x).__name__` and `type(x).__module__` to determine if it understands the type
- It seems that any indexable object can be placed in the `._data` attribute

Unfortunately, matlab is not using the `_data` attribute efficiently internally, and is iterating over it one item at a time rather than using the python `memoryview` protocol :(. So the speed gain is marginal with this approach.

Comment: The speed up should be quite significant. I got about a factor of 15 with this method. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45290997/4045774

Comment: @max9111: Did you find that wrapping with `array.array` (as you do there) vs not doing so (as I do here) made any difference?

Comment: Yes, your version is faster ;). Maybe it would be good to clarify that your solution is actually drastically faster than the matlab.double(np_a.tolist()).

Comment: For situations where you'd like to avoid the data duplication on the filesystem and any I/O related time, this seems like the best option.

Comment: For a 100 x 100 x 100 array, this approach takes 2.73 ms ± 191 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each), but matlab.double takes1.12 s ± 58.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each). Around 400x speed up...

Answer (score 4):

scipy.io.savemat or scipy.io.loadmat does NOT work for matlab arrays --v7.3. But the good part is that matlab --v7.3 files are hdf5 datasets. So they can be read using a number of tools, including numpy.

For python, you will need the [h5py](http://www.h5py.org/docs/intro/build.html) extension, which requires [HDF5](http://www.hdfgroup.org/downloads/index.html) on your system.

```
import numpy as np, h5py 
f = h5py.File('somefile.mat','r') 
data = f.get('data/variable1') 
data = np.array(data) # For converting to numpy array
```

Answer (score 2):

Some time ago I faced the same problem and wrote the following scripts to allow easy copy and pasting of arrays back and forth from interactive sessions. Obviously only practical for small arrays, but I found it more convenient than saving/loading through a file every time:

[Matlab -> Python](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24087)

[Python -> Matlab](http://codepad.org/MVYCM0AJ)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it counts as "simpler" but I found a solution to move data from a numpy arrray created in a python script which is called by matlab quite fast:

dump_reader.py (python source):

```
import numpy

def matlab_test2():
    np_a    = numpy.random.uniform(low = 0.0, high = 30000.0, size = (1000,1000))
    return np_a
```

dump_read.m (matlab script):

```
clear classes
mod = py.importlib.import_module('dump_reader');
py.importlib.reload(mod);

if count(py.sys.path,'') == 0
    insert(py.sys.path,int32(0),'');
end

tic
A = py.dump_reader.matlab_test2();
toc
shape = cellfun(@int64,cell(A.shape));
ls = py.array.array('d',A.flatten('F').tolist());
p = double(ls);
toc
C = reshape(p,shape);
toc
```

It relies on the fact that matlabs double seems be working efficiently on arrays compared to cells/matrices. Second trick is to pass the data to matlabs double in an efficient way (via pythons native array.array).

P.S. sorry for necroposting but I struggled a lot with its and this topic was one of the closest hits. Maybe it helps someone to shorten the time of struggling.

P.P.S. tested with Matlab R2016b + python 3.5.4 (64bit)

Answer (score 2):

The python library [Darr](https://github.com/gbeckers/Darr) allows you to save your Python numpy arrays in a self-documenting and widely readable format, consisting of just binary and text files. When saving your array, it will include code to read that array in a variety of languages, including Matlab. So in essence, it is just one line to save your numpy array to disk in Python, and then copy-paste the code from the README.txt to load it into Matlab.

Disclosure: I wrote the library.

Comment: Interesting! Please add a disclosure if you are the same Gabriel as the one that wrote the library.

Answer (score 1):

From MATLAB R2022a on, matlab.double (and matlab.int8, matlab.uint8, etc.) objects implement the buffer protocol. This means that you can pass them into NumPy array constructors. Construction in the opposite direction (which is the subject of the question here) is supported as well. That is, matlab objects can be constructed from objects that implement the buffer protocol. Thus, for instance, a matlab.double can be constructed from a NumPy double array.

UPDATE: Furthermore, from MATLAB R2022b on, objects that implement the buffer protocol (such as NumPy objects) can be passed directly into MATLAB functions that are called via Python. From the [MATLAB Release Notes](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html) for R2022b, under the "External Language Interfaces" section:

```
import matlab.engine
import numpy
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
buf = numpy.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], dtype='uint16')

# Supported in R2022a and earlier: must initialize a matlab.uint16 from
# the numpy array and pass it to the function
array_as_matlab_uint16 = matlab.uint16(buf)
res = eng.sum(array_as_matlab_uint16, 1, 'native')
print(res)

# Supported as of R2022b: can pass the numpy array
# directly to the function
res = eng.sum(buf, 1, 'native')
print(res)
```

Comment: it would be great if you could provide examples

Comment: It's actually quite simple, and explained here: https://de.mathworks.com/content/dam/mathworks/fact-sheet/using-matlab-with-python-cheat-sheet.pdf. 
To convert the matlab array MLA into python numpy array it is enough to do np.array(MLA)

Comment: @fabiob, I added a section entitled "UPDATE", which includes an example. But the fact sheet you mentioned doesn't seem to actually cover the MATLAB<->NumPy conversion. Did you mean to link to something else?

Comment: yeah... but it says "Data types will be automatically converted where possible." and "Some MATLAB data types need to be converted" so it helped me infer the solution (I was interested in the direction matlab->python)

Answer (score 0):

Let use say you have a 2D daily data with shape (365,10) for five years saved in np array `np3Darrat` that will have a shape (5,365,10). In python save your np array:

```
import scipy.io as sio     #SciPy module to load and save mat-files
m['np3Darray']=np3Darray   #shape(5,365,10)
sio.savemat('file.mat',m)  #Save np 3D array
```

Then in MATLAB convert np 3D array to MATLAB 3D matix:

```
load('file.mat','np3Darray')
M3D=permute(np3Darray, [2 3 1]);   %Convert numpy array with shape (5,365,10) to MATLAB matrix with shape (365,10,5)
```

Answer (score 0):

In latest R2021a, you can pass a python numpy ndarray to double() and it will convert to a native matlab matrix, even when calling in console the numpy array it will suggest at the bottom "Use double function to convert to a MATLAB array"