# How to find wrong prediction cases in test set (CNNs using Keras)

Tags: python, machine-learning, theano, convolution, keras

I'm using MNIST example with 60000 training image and 10000 testing image. How do I find which of the 10000 testing image that has an incorrect classification/prediction?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Simply use `model.predict_classes()` and compare the output with true labes. i.e:

```
incorrects = np.nonzero(model.predict_class(X_test).reshape((-1,)) != y_test)
```

to get indices of incorrect predictions

Comment: How can I generate a sub-folder with the wrong classified cases inside each class folder??

Comment: if x, y are numpy check out the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28440249/13717851)

Answer (score 2):

> Editing as was not clear earlier

To identify the image files that are wrongly classified, you can use:

```
fnames = test_generator.filenames ## fnames is all the filenames/samples used in testing
errors = np.where(y_pred != test_generator.classes)[0] ## misclassifications done on the test data where y_pred is the predicted values
for i in errors:
    print(fnames[i])
```

Comment: What are all the variables?

Comment: How can I print the actual class and predicted class as well along with the image name?

Comment: when I print fnames, it printed same file name multiple times. Any update?