# Pandas dataframe reading numpy array column as str

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two Python scripts, one that creates a `.csv` file and the other one that reads it.

This is how I save the dataframe in the first file:

```
df['matrix'] = df['matrix'].apply(lambda x: np.array(x))
df.to_csv("Matrices.csv", sep=",", index=False)
```

The type and shape of `df['matrix'].iloc[0]` is `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>` and `(24, 60)` respectively.

In the second script when I try

```
print ("type of df['matrix'].iloc[0]", type(df['matrix'].iloc[0]))
```

The output is `type of df['matrix'].iloc[0] <class 'str'>`

How can I make sure that `df['matrix']` doesn't loose its nature?

Comment: What does the `csv` look like?  How did it render the array object?  My guess it included [], as might be produced by `str(df['matrix'][0]`.

Answer (score 2):

If want save and read only numpy array use [`savetxt`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28440249/2901002) and [`genfromtxt`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3518778/2901002).

---

If there are multiple columns then use:

Use [pickle](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#pickling):

```
df.to_pickle('file.pkl')
df = pd.read_pickle('file.pkl')
```

---

Convert arrays to multiple columns and then write to file:

```
a = np.array(
[[219,220,221],
 [154,152,14],
 [205,202,192]])

df = pd.DataFrame({'matrix':a.tolist(), 'b':np.arange(len(a))})
print (df)
            matrix  b
0  [219, 220, 221]  0
1   [154, 152, 14]  1
2  [205, 202, 192]  2

df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.pop('matrix').values.tolist(), index=df.index).add_prefix('mat_')
print (df1)
   mat_0  mat_1  mat_2
0    219    220    221
1    154    152     14
2    205    202    192

df = df.join(df1)
print (df)
   b  mat_0  mat_1  mat_2
0  0    219    220    221
1  1    154    152     14
2  2    205    202    192
```

But if really need to convert values to `array` need converter with `ast.literal_eval`:

```
import ast

df.to_csv('testing.csv', index=False)

df = pd.read_csv('testing.csv', converters={'matrix':lambda x: np.array(ast.literal_eval(x))})
print (type(df.loc[0, 'matrix']))

<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Comment: I was initially using np.array(list(map(literal_eval, df['matrix']))) but my Python interpreter collapses while working on full dataset. Is there any other alternative?

Comment: @yaminigoel - What about `df.to_pickle(file)` and `df = pd.read_pickle(file)` ?

Comment: I didn't know about `pickle` functionality. Does it work fine with `.csv`? My script crashes when I try `df.to_pickle("Matrices.csv")`

Comment: @yaminigoel - What is error? Because `to_csv` always lost types of data, all data are always converted to strings. And then `read_csv` distinguish only floats and int columns, another are converted to strings.

Answer (score 1):

For saving arrays directly to csv as multiple columns use:

```
np.savetxt(r'C:\path\file.csv',a,delimiter=',')
```

If you need to read back as a python object, `ast.literal_eval()` is your saviour as pointed by @jezrael

Comment: I was initially using `np.array(list(map(literal_eval, df['matrix'])))` but my Python interpreter collapses while working on full dataset. Is there any other alternative?