# how to import a csv file, with a column that have a list of arrays in it in python?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, list, csv

I have a `.csv` file with a column `similarity_all` that contains a list of arrays in it. When i'm importing the file with `pd.read_csv()` method, the column comes as a string.

How can i transform this field to be a list of arrays, like it's supose to be?

[dataframe imported with the field "similarity_all" as string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3aWs.png)

Comment: Can you paste the output of `df.head().to_dict()` so we can work with the exact strings?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas dataframe reading numpy array column as str](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54614635/pandas-dataframe-reading-numpy-array-column-as-str)

Comment: Could you show an example of how the list of arrays is formatted please?