# how to communicate a numpy Nd array as as part of a minimal example?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

What's the best way to communicate array values as part of a minimal example in a python question on StackOverflow or Github?  R has the function [dump()](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/dump.html), which produces a text representation of an object that can then be loaded back into an R session using [source()](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/source.html).  Two lines of R code and someone else has access to the numbers/object/whatever I'm working with.

I want to raise an issue at the [holoviews](http://holoviews.org/index.html)/[geoviews](http://geoviews.org/index.html) GitHub repo about some problems I'm having making regional plots of gridded data.  I suspect that the problem is partially related to nature of my grid, which is a 36x36 irregularly-spaced array of latitudes and longitudes.

Since it's not that many points I'm thinking it's probably easiest to simply include these coordinates in my question/issue.  I can probably figure out something with [fromstring()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html) and [reshape()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html).  I wondered if there's a more concise way to do it.

Comment: Many questions just do something like `arrayname = np.array([1, 2, 3])`

Comment: Or `arrayname = np.zeros((2, 3))`

Comment: `np.savetxt()` and `np.loadtxt()` https://stackoverflow.com/a/28440249/2836621

Comment: For modest sized arrays, the `repr` display is useful.  `'array([0, 0, 3])'`. It looks a lot like the code that is used to create an array from a (nested) list.  Browse other `numpy` questions, and pay attention to the answers.  A number of higher-ranked posters copy-n-paste their answer from `ipython` sessions, showing both input and output code.

Answer (score 0):

This existing answer shows how to use `json.dumps()` to serialise to a string, although as numpy arrays are not directly serialisable, they need to be converted to a list first:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51836953/3592211