# Saving 4D array without losing its format

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, save, google-colaboratory

I have this 4D array (numpy.ndarray) that I need to save in a way that its format does not change as I save it (since it should remain unchanged), and then reuse it in my Google Colab file. I have tried saving it in different formats and when I upload it and preview it within my code, the previous format is no longer preserved even when I save it in the .npy format. I have also tried importing the date using the raw link from my GitHub repository or uploading it from my local device, but still no chance. I would appreciate your comments regarding the issue!

Further elaboration:

Here is the code that I use to generate my 4D array:

```
num1=100000
size = (num1, 8, 4, 4)
prob_0 = 0.3 # 30% of zeros
prob_1 = 1 - prob_0 # 70% of ones
P = np.random.choice([0, 1], size=size, p=[prob_0, prob_1])
```

I need to save this P as a file and use it in Google Colab. I have to save it in order to maintain the initial data and not come up with a different 4D array every time I run my code. This data (i.e. P) must remain unchanged.

Comment: You can try `numpy` file format

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save and load numpy.array() data properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28439701/how-to-save-and-load-numpy-array-data-properly)

Comment: Saving/loading 4D numpy array works for me. Can you provide more details, is this simple 4D array and what do you mean by format is not preserved?

Comment: You need to be more specific about how you save the array.  Test the array - shape and dtype before saving.  Then test a load on the same machine.  Then move on to test on the uploaded.  If there is a difference, describe it exactly.  A general "if doesn't work" question won't elicit good answers.  Normally the default `np.save/load` pair works.

Comment: @crayxt  Thank you for your comment. I have updated my question with further info.

Comment: @hpaulj Thank you for your comment. I just added some further info to my question.

Comment: @Don'tAccept It works with 1D or 2D arrays, but not in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usual `np.save`, `np.load` works

```
>>> P.shape
(100000, 8, 4, 4)
>>> np.save("P.npy", P)
>>> P2 = np.load("P.npy")
>>> P2.shape
(100000, 8, 4, 4)
>>> np.allclose(P, P2)
True
```

Comment: I tried this but since its a dict object when I upload the .npy file to Google Colab and print it I get a message starting like this:
{'P.npy': b"\x93NUMPY\x01\x00v\x00{'descr': '<i8', 'fortran_order': False, 'shape': (100000, 8, 4, 4), }

Comment: 1) Could it be that Google Collab messes up with `.npy` files?

Comment: 2) Have you tried to set `np.seed(number)` to get constant results?

Comment: Yes, I tried it on my Jupyter notebook and it worked properly. Thank you so much!