# Is there a Python analog to matlab's "save()" function?

Tags: python, numpy

Say I ran some code that produces multiple arrays as its output. How might I save the entire output in one go as in matlab?

In matlab I'd simply say `save(data)` -> `load('data')`.

Apologies if this is a basic quesiton.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960864/how-to-save-all-the-variables-in-the-current-python-session

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save and load numpy.array() data properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28439701/how-to-save-and-load-numpy-array-data-properly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### How to save a python object:

To save objects to file in Python, you can use `pickle`:

- Import the `pickle` module.
- Get a file handle in write mode that points
  to a file path.
- Use `pickle.dump` to write the object that we want to
  save to file via that file handle.

##### How to use it:

```
   import pickle 
   object = Object() 
   filehandler = open(filename, 'w') 
   pickle.dump(object, filehandler)
```

### How to load a python object:

- Import the `pickle` module.
- Get a file handle in read mode that points to a file path that has a file that contains the serialized form of a Python object.
- Use `pickle.load` to read the object from the file that contains the serialized form of a Python object via the file handle.

##### How to use it:

```
   import pickle 
   filehandler = open(filename, 'r') 
   object = pickle.load(filehandler)
```

---

##### Extras : save multiple objects at once

Obviously, using a list you can also store multiple objects at once:

```
object_a = "foo"
object_b = "bar"
object_c = "baz"

objects_list = [object_a , object_b , object_c ]
file_name = "my_objects.pkl"
open_file = open(file_name, "wb")
pickle.dump(objects_list, open_file)
open_file.close()
```

Comment: This is a bit different from MATLAB `save`, which saves the entire workspace.

Comment: You're right, anyway i edited my answer to save multiple objects at once. It's not the same of MATLAB save, but it actually works in practice.