# How does dtype of Numpy array affect memory usage when calling .tolist()?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, python-xarray, dtype

I'm wondering how different `dtype` of numpy arrays affect the memory usage in Python when calling `.tolist()` on the array. I want to conserve as much memory as possible. If I am correct, using `float16` shoudl allow me to carry double the amount of values when compared to `float32` because `float16` uses half as much memory as `float32` but the thing is I don't seem to see a difference in the `byte` size when I call `.tolist()` onto the `numpy` array. Does Python not conserve the `dtype` and just revert everything to the exact same `dtype` or am I missing something in my observations?

Example:

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import sys

x = xr.DataArray(np.arange(6).reshape(2,3),dims=["lat","lon"],coords={"lat":[1,2], "lon": [0,1,2]})

m = xr.zeros_like(x, dtype= 'float64')
m2 = xr.zeros_like(x, dtype= 'float32')
m3 = xr.zeros_like(x, dtype= 'float16')

print("m")
print(m.dtype)
print(m.nbytes)
print(sys.getsizeof(m))
print(sys.getsizeof(m.values.flatten.tolist()))

print("m2")
print(m2.dtype)
print(m2.nbytes)
print(sys.getsizeof(m2))
print(sys.getsizeof(m2.values.faltten.tolist()))

print("m3")
print(m3.dtype)
print(m3.nbytes)
print(sys.getsizeof(m3))
print(sys.getsizeof(m3.values.flatten.tolist()))
```

The output is the following:

```
m
float64
48
56
80
m2
float32
24
56
80
m3
float16
12
56
80
```

It states that calling `.tolist()` uses `80 bytes` regardless of `dtype`. So my question is, is there even any benefit to memeory usage in python when  converting `numpy array` to `list` in python. Is there ANY memory benefit at all at ANY point in the process of `m3.values.tolist()` with regards to using a different `dtype` for the `numpy` data or is there no point in trying to conserve memory usage and am I just lowering precision using `float16`

Comment: `getsizeof` is nearly useless when applied to a list.

Comment: so the output is inaccurate?

Comment: If the end result is a json file, that should be clearer in the question (and the tags).

Comment: I'm calling getsizeof on the list after I call tolist on the numpy array. I wan to put the list into a JSON file after but am trying to minimize memory consumption of the actual list object by reducing the memory consumption of the values in the list (float16 instead of float32)

Comment: If you care about the memory usage, then you should never use a list. Lists contains reference to Python objects. This is typically float for Numpy arrays of type float64/float32/float16. Pure-Python floats take far more memory than a native float because they are full object, not to mention the reference in the list. AFAIR, it takes 40 bytes per item as opposed to 8 bytes/item for a float64-based array. If the memory usage is so important and you need to use a list, then consider extracting chunks of the array. If you cannot, then the memory usage will be mandatory higher.

Comment: `getsizeof` only measures the size of the array that stores the references.  It does not report the size of the referenced objects.  So it could not distinguish between "small floats" and "long ones", even if that difference exists.  As others point out, `tolist` produces a pure Python list, so the elements can only be Python floats (or ints).

Comment: @JérômeRichard, from the comments it appears that the OP is really concerned with memory use during the production of a JSON string.  Unless `xarray` has some specialized JSON serializer, `tolist` is the only way to go.

Answer (score 2):

```
In [39]: x = xr.DataArray(np.arange(6).reshape(2,3),dims=["lat","lon"],coords={"lat":[1,2], "lon": [0,1,2]})
    ...: 
    ...: m = xr.zeros_like(x, dtype= 'float64')
    ...: m2 = xr.zeros_like(x, dtype= 'float32')
    ...: m3 = xr.zeros_like(x, dtype= 'float16')

In [40]: m.shape
Out[40]: (2, 3)
```

Because `m` is 2d, the list equivalent is a list of lists.  Keep that in mind when considering memory use.

```
In [41]: m.values.tolist()
Out[41]: [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
```

First check the type of individual numeric elements - all the same:

```
In [42]: type(m.values.tolist()[0][0])
Out[42]: float    
In [43]: type(m2.values.tolist()[0][0])
Out[43]: float    
In [44]: type(m3.values.tolist()[0][0])
Out[44]: float
```

As for `getsizeof` applied to list - it just measures the memory allocated for storing references (plus some overhead):

```
In [45]: sys.getsizeof(m.values.tolist())        # a len 2 list
Out[45]: 72

In [46]: sys.getsizeof(m.values.tolist()[0])     # a len 3 list (on more pointer)
Out[46]: 80
```

An individual float:

```
In [47]: sys.getsizeof(m.values.tolist()[0][0])
Out[47]: 24
```

So total size will be 72 + 2*80 + 6*24

Since your goal is a json string (or file) let's try encoding:

```
In [48]: import json
In [50]: json.dumps(m.values.tolist())
Out[50]: '[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]'
```

But for random float values:

```
In [55]: json.dumps(np.random.randn(2,3).tolist())
Out[55]: '[[0.8431542062798922, 0.939582071772101, 0.8783338312384453], [-0.5734061911788975, -0.3403280836021266, 0.39779755792940164]]'
```

Fiddling with the dtype of the source array changes nothing.

Comment: forgot to mention that I'm calling`.flatten` so It should be a 1D array.

Comment: For flattened arrays it may be possible to serialize it with `tobytes` or `tostring`.  I think there have been other `numpy/json` questions.

Comment: do all python objects take the same amount of memory? Or does a string consume less than float/int, does the lenght of the string matter etc...

Answer (score 1):

Calling `tolist` returns a pure-python object, so it returns a list of floats. Python has no distinction of different sizes of floats -- they are all of the same type.

```
m_l = m.tolist()
m2_l = m2.tolist()
m3_l = m3.tolist()

print(type(m_l[0][0]))        # <class 'float'>
print(type(m2_l[0][0]))       # <class 'float'>
print(type(m3_l[0][0]))       # <class 'float'>

print(type(m_l[0][0]) == type(m2_l[0][0]) == type(m3_l[0][0]))
# True
```

---

> is there even any benefit to memory usage in python when converting numpy array to list in python. Is there ANY memory benefit at all at ANY point in the process of `m3.values.tolist()` with regards to using a different dtype for the numpy data or is there no point in trying to conserve memory usage and am I just lowering precision using float16

Here's a comparison of runtimes for functions that sum an array by

1. Iterating over `arr.tolist()`
2. Iterating over `arr` directly
3. Calling the numpy method `arr.sum()`

[image]

While iterating over `arr.tolist()` is faster than simply iterating over the array, calling `arr.sum()` is faster for large arrays. If you *must* iterate over the array, you could do it using `.tolist`, but as far as possible you should try to do it within numpy.

The choice of dtype depends on what you're using the array for. If you're using it for lat/lon, think about what is the max value it can be? Since calculations between `float16` and `float16` will yield another `float16`, can you do calculations in `float16` precision?

---

Timing code:

```
import timeit
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def time_funcs(funcs, sizes, arg_gen, N=20):
    times = np.zeros((len(sizes), len(funcs)))
    gdict = globals().copy()
    for i, s in enumerate(sizes):
        args = arg_gen(s)
        print(args)
        for j, f in enumerate(funcs):
            gdict.update(locals())
            try:
                times[i, j] = timeit.timeit("f(*args)", globals=gdict, number=N) / N
                print(f"{i}/{len(sizes)}, {j}/{len(funcs)}, {times[i, j]}")
            except ValueError:
                print("ERROR in {f}({*args})")
                
            
    return times

def plot_times(times, funcs):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    for j, f in enumerate(funcs):
        ax.plot(sizes, times[:, j], label=f.__name__)
    
    
    ax.set_xlabel("Array size")
    ax.set_ylabel("Time per function call (s)")
    ax.set_xscale("log")
    ax.set_yscale("log")
    ax.legend()
    ax.grid()
    fig.tight_layout()
    return fig, ax

#%%
def arg_gen(n):
    return [np.random.random((n,))]

#%%
def sum_iter_tolist(arr):
    lst = arr.tolist()
    x = 0
    for i in lst:
        x += i
    return x

def sum_iter_arr(arr):
    x = 0
    for i in arr:
        x += i
    return x
    
def sum_numpy(arr):
    return np.sum(arr)


#%% 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    #%% Set up sim
    # sizes = [5, 10, 50, 100, 500, 1000, 5000, 10_000, 50_000, 100_000]
    sizes = [5, 10, 50, 100, 500, 1000, 5000, 10_000, 50_000, 100_000, 1_000_000, 5_000_000]
    funcs = [sum_iter_tolist, sum_iter_arr, sum_numpy]
    
    
    #%% Run timing
    time_fcalls = np.zeros((len(sizes), len(funcs))) * np.nan
    time_fcalls = time_funcs(funcs, sizes, arg_gen)
    
    #%%
    fig, ax = plot_times(time_fcalls, funcs)
    ax.set_xlabel(f"Input size")
    plt.show()
```

Comment: so there is no way to conserve memory usage when using floats in python, every float regardless of precision needed etc uses the exact same number of bytes?

Comment: @user20816596 I'm not sure what you're trying to conserve memory for. Any gain in conserved memory is lost in the time it takes to convert your array to a list, and we haven't even thought about what you're going to do with the list. But yes, every python `float` is a numpy `float64`

Comment: I am trying to output data into a json file but running into memory issues when using .tolist(), hence trying to conserve memory. My thought was that using dtype = float16, i could output double the values of data while still using the same amount of memory as dtype = float32

Comment: doing `json.dumps('numpy_array_object')` results in `TypeError: Object of type ndarry is not JSON serializable`

Comment: JSON is a text format, essentially formatting list, dict, strings and numbers.  You do need to use `tolist`.   Do you hit memory errors in the `tolist` step, or in the json construction?

Comment: `tolist()` is useful if you must iterate on an array.  `for i in arr.tolist():` speeds up the iteration.  Effectively `tolist` is faster than `list(arr)`.  But if the focus is memory use, `tolist` does nothing.   Lists and arrays each have their strong points, and should be used accordingly.

Comment: @hpaulj is `.tolist()` and then iterating still faster than just iterating over the array?

Comment: Yes, at least in the cases I've tested.  Iteration on an array requires an element-by-element "unboxing", e.g.  `arr[0]` etc.  That's much slower than accessing an element of a list, `alist[0]`.  And `tolist` is a compiled method, and comparatively fast.

Comment: Makes sense. I just ran a quick test, and iterating over `tolist()` is indeed faster. https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXW9j.png

Comment: I'm not doing any calculations with the data, just need to output it to a JSON. So doing `for i in arr.tolist()` would be faster than just doing `arr.tolist()`. And seems that there in no way I could save on memory usage? Would using a `generator` be of any help to memory at all, or am I stuck with the the memory situation because everything has to be a python float.

Comment: If you must make them python floats, you must take the memory hit. You might be able to save on memory by using `json.dump` instead of `dumps` by probably not having the entire string in memory at once (I'm not sure it works this way for json though)

Comment: If you want to store data, you might consider the solutions shown in https://stackoverflow.com/q/28439701/843953 instead of json. Maybe the json could point to a separate file that holds the data for an array, and you could write a reader to read the appropriate file when the json is deserialized